# Xcode failed run diagnostic error in Version 14.3.1 (14E300c)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have been facing this problem in the newest Xcode version, Version 14.3.1.

I was following the codes from Hacking With Swift, 100 Days of SwiftUI. While following the guy's code, I faced the problem: " failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs)." I rechecked my code with the video, ChatGPT, BardAI, and a bunch of other tools. It kept giving me that error. I reported to Apple right now, but I have no idea how to fix is, so I need your help.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  WeSplit2
//
//  Created by Oliver Park on 2023/07/04.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var checkAmount = 0.0
    @State private var numberOfPeople = 2
    @State private var tipPercentage = 20
    
    let tipPercentages = [10, 15, 20, 25, 0]
    
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Amount", value: $checkAmount, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currency?.identifier ?? "USD"))
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    Picker("Number of people", selection: $numberOfPeople) {
                    ForEach(2..<100) {
                            Text("\($0) people")
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Section {
                    Picker("Tip percentage", selection: $tipPercentage) {
                        ForEach(tipPercentages, id: \.self) { percentage in
                            Text(String(percentage), format: .percent)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Section {
                    Text(checkAmount, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currency?.identifier ?? "USD"))
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("WeSplit")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code doesn't match what was used in the tutorial. Specifically, this:

```swift
Text(String(percentage), format: .percent)
```

Should really be this:

```swift
Text(percentage, format: .percent)
```

I hope that helps!